# Python file overwriting script

Tags: python, beginner, comparative-review, file

I am fairly new to Python and I'm trying to make a script that does three basic things: prints the contents of a file, overwrites it with your new lines, and prints the new file. I rewrote the script with functions and was looking for critiques. Is this a good use of functions? What would you do different?

```
print("Type the name of the file for overwriting.")
file = input(">")
x = open(file)
print("The contents are currently: \n", x.read())
print("Enter in the new lines")
l1 = input(">")
l2 = input(">")
l3 = input(">")
x.close()

y = open(file, 'w')

print("Entering new lines.")

y.write(l1 + '\n' + l2 + '\n' + l3)
y.close()

z = open(file).read()
print("The new contents are:")
print(z)
```

Script with functions:

```
def open_and_read(x):
    print(open(x).read())

def nl(x):
    z.write(x + '\n')

temp = ">"  
print("Type the name of the file for overwriting.")
file = input(temp)
print(f"The current content of {file} is:")
open_and_read(file)

z = open(file, 'w')

print("Enter in three new lines of text:")
l1 = input(temp)
l2 = input(temp)
l3 = input(temp)

nl(l1)
nl(l2)
nl(l3)

z.close()

print("The new contents are:")
open_and_read(file)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely switch to using [`with` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) which is gonna safely and automatically close the opened file handler.

Also, you need to improve your variable names, `l1`, `l2`, `l3` or `z` are not descriptive.

And, you may use `.writelines()` to write a list of strings each of them on a separate line.

In the end, you might get something along these lines:

```
print("Type the name of the file for overwriting.")
file_name = input(">")

with open(file_name) as input_file:
    print("The contents are currently: \n", input_file.read())
    print("Enter in the new lines")

lines = [input(">") for _ in range(3)]

print("Entering new lines.")
with open(file_name, 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(lines)

with open(file_name) as input_file:
    print("The new contents are:")
    print(input_file.read())
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a good use of functions?

**Not really**, take this function for example:

```
def nl(x):
    z.write(x + '\n')
```

It is not descriptive at all

1. Where does the variable `z` comes from?
2. `z` is a global variable out of scope of the function. (which is **BAD**)
3. What does `nl` stand for?

When writing good functions it's better to have longer descriptive names.
Your other function `open_and_read()` has a way better name, although that could also use some improvement.

**How to write good function?**

```
def write_to_file(filename, content):
    """Writes content to a file."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write_lines(content)
```

This would be a better function, because.

1. Has descripte variable names
2. A nice doctring to explain what the function does
3. A function name, where it is clear on first sight what that function does